# Hsqldb-How data will persist when process crashes

Tags: hsqldb

I want data should commit in hsqldb data file while process crashes without logging to log file. I set one command "SET FILES WRITE DELAY FALSE" But it needs log file enabled to persist the data.As logging will create performance impact i dont want it.So is there any way to achive this objective.

what is the impact of logging in Application.

Thanks in Advance,
Anil

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB writes data to the .log file by default. This .log file is used for recovery in case of a crash.

When `SET FILES WRITE DELAY FALSE` is set, the engine performs a file sync on the .log file at each commit. The reason for the performance impact is the file sync operation. This setting is useful for tests, when many changes are written quickly and the process always exists. It is not necessary for many applications, as by default, a sync is performed on the .log file every .5 second if new records have been written. This can be reduced to 100 milliseconds without a big impact on performance.

You can turn logging off with the `SET FILES LOG FALSE` statement and perform mass inserts or updates, but this is not recommended as a default setting.

At anytime, including when logging has been turned off , you can perform an explicit CHECKPOINT to commit all the data to the .data and .script files.